# Copy files or directories while excluding multiple files or directories

Tags: linux

```
[@ysx-dlfwq-2 555]$ tree
.
├── 666
├── 777
│   └── 71.sh
├── 888
│   └── 8881
├── test2.sh
├── test.sh
└── test.txt

4 directories, 4 files

After executing the command
find /opt/share/555/ -mindepth 1 -type d \( -path /opt/share/555/666 -o -path /opt/share/555/888/8881 \) -o -type f \( -path /opt/share/555/test.txt \) -prune -o -exec cp -prf {} /opt/share/2/ \;

[@ysx-dlfwq-2 2]# tree
.
├── 71.sh           <<<----Files that should not appear
├── 777
│   └── 71.sh
├── 888
│   └── 8881        <<<----Directory that should not appear
├── test2.sh
└── test.sh

3 directories, 4 files
```

Our environment only allows the use of built-in system commands, and rsync is not within consideration. If there are no commands that support regular expressions that I am currently aware of, could the experts please lend a hand?

Comment: I'm not really clear what the problem is here. You show a "file that should not appear", but you're not explicitly filtering that out in your `find` command. What are the rules you want to apply to your copy operation?

Answer (score 1):

I'm a little unclear about what you're trying to accomplish, but...

You can use `find` to generate a list of files to copy, pass that through `grep` to filter it, and pipe the result to `cpio` to actually copy the files:

```
find /opt/share/555/ -type f |
  grep -v 'whatever' |
  cpio -pd /opt/share/2
```

This allows you to use regular expression to control what does or does not get copied.